# How to access data from twig extension that returns array?

Tags: php, twig

I have a custom Twig extension that returns an array:

```
$base64Decode = new Twig_Filter('base64_decode', function ($string) {
    return unserialize(base64_decode($string));
});
```

in my template I can see the array arrive using {{ dump(i.extra|base64_decode) }} and it outputs:

```
array(5) { ["discount"]=> int(0) ["product_size"]=> string(5) "Fruit" ["sub1"]=> string(0) "" ["sub2"]=> string(0) "" ["sub3"]=> string(0)
```

But I can't figure out how access the values I need... This does not work:

```
{% for x in (i.extra|base64_decode) %}
product_size: {{x.product_size}}
sub1: {{x.sub1}}
sub2: {{x.sub2}}
sub3: {{.xsub3}}
{% endfor %}
```

This for loop is within another loop, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter returns array, so you need to assign output of it to variable by [`set`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/set.html):

```
{% set data = i.extra|base64_decode %}
{{ data.product_size }}
```

Comment: That totally works! I must say I find the Twig documentation rather "minimalist"... The page for set could really use your example! I assumed I needed to use a for loop...